# What is the best way to show readonly/editable controls on MVC Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to show readonly or editable controls on a MVC razor page based on permissions. I have used scaffolding and have used ternary operator to show readonly/editable controls on Razor View. Is there a better way to do it without having to write conditional logic into a Razor View? Please help...

Thank you

Comment: If this is permission-based, you may consider not rendering fields at all and simply displaying the plain-text value if the user does not have access. A user with just a little initiative can easily undo the readonly status of any field. At the very least, you should recheck permissions on POST and ensure that changes are not saved if the user is not allowed.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, yes I am displaying plain text if the user does not have permission and yes I am doing a check on POST as well, so question remains is this the only way (using conditional statements in view)?

Answer (score 3):

you can set it once.  At the top of your view:

```
@{ string readonly = (somePermission) ? "readonly" : "";
```

then:

```
<input type="text" @readonly>
```

then you'll only ever have to change it in one place, and won't sacrifice performance

Comment: What if your using `@Html.TextBoxFor(...)`?

Comment: @mxmissile you can use this signature of the method: @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.YourField, new { readonly = somePermission }). If somePermission is null, the attribute won't be added to the tag.